# COM function that return BSTR** does not work as it seems to me it should , but same function not from COM work like expected

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, com

I am trying to write a COM object with Windows Service Managment functionality. For this, I want a function that returns the names of all services. I've been familiar with Windows Api for a few days, so I don't really understand what I'm doing (wrong) and how I can do it better.

```
STDMETHODIMP CServiceHandler::GetServices(BSTR** pOut, LPDWORD dwServicesReturned)
{
    SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
    if (!hSCManager)
    {

        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    DWORD dwBytesNeeded = 0;
    DWORD dwResumeHandle = 0;

    EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_STATE_ALL, NULL, 0, &dwBytesNeeded, dwServicesReturned, &dwResumeHandle);

    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_MORE_DATA)
    {

        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS lpServices = (LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS)malloc(dwBytesNeeded);
    if (!EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_STATE_ALL, lpServices, dwBytesNeeded, &dwBytesNeeded, dwServicesReturned, &dwResumeHandle))
    {

        free(lpServices);
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    }

    BSTR* pServiceNames = (BSTR*)malloc(*dwServicesReturned * sizeof(BSTR));
    if (!pServiceNames)
    {
        free(lpServices);
        CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }

    ZeroMemory(pServiceNames, *dwServicesReturned * sizeof(BSTR));



    for (DWORD i = 0; i < *dwServicesReturned; i++)
    {
        
        pServiceNames[i] = SysAllocString(lpServices[i].lpServiceName);
    }

      *pOut = pServiceNames;
//    //return S_OK;
      free(lpServices);
 
      CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
      return S_OK;
```

In another program where I call this function this way:

```
...
    BSTR* pServiceNames = (BSTR*)CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(BSTR));;
    DWORD dwServicesReturned = 0;
    hr = pIService->GetServices(&pServiceNames, &dwServicesReturned);
...
```

Then I try something like this:

`std::wcout << (pServiceNames[0]);  // result: AdobeARMservice`

`std::wcout << (pServiceNames[1]);  // result: (process 8844) exited with code -1073741819.`

Same if use "printf". And
`std::cout << (pServiceNames[1]); //result: 000000084D454D4C`

When I paste the same function into my main program, everything is fine, i.e. all the service names are displayed.

Additional information: For COM I used ATL, maybe it's important.

Comment: `BSTR**` is a rather awkward type to use in a COM interface. If you need to return an array (of `BSTR`'s) it's much more common to use a [`SAFEARRAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/ns-oaidl-safearray) instead. Also, as far as error reporting goes, pretty much every other call to `GetLastError` is running too late, returning indeterminate values to clients.

Answer (score 1):

Your handling of `EnumServiceStatus()` is incomplete, as you are not taking `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER` into account.  Any given call to `EnumServiceStatus()` may require more memory, thus reporting `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`, or it may return only a subset of data, reporting `ERROR_MORE_DATA`. You need to handle both cases, as well as the fact that when `ERROR_MORE_DATA` is reported, some valid data may have been returned which you need to process.  So, you may end up having to reallocate your `BSTR` array more than once during the course of your enumeration.

Also, all memory passed around in COM needs to be allocated with COM's memory manager, but `GetServices()` is allocating the output `BSTR` array using `malloc()`.  Your calling code is calling `CoTaskMemAlloc()` locally before calling `GetServices()`, and then `GetServices()` is overwriting the caller's pointer, thus leaking the memory that the caller allocated.  The caller should not be allocating any memory locally at all, only taking ownership of the memory that `GetServices()` outputs.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
STDMETHODIMP CServiceHandler::GetServices(BSTR** pServices, LPDWORD pdwServicesReturned)
{
    if (!(pServices && pdwServicesReturned))
        return E_POINTER;

    *pServices = NULL;
    *pdwServicesReturned = 0;

    SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE);
    if (!hSCManager)
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS lpStatuses = NULL;
    DWORD dwBytesAllocated = 0;
    DWORD dwBytesNeeded = 0;
    DWORD dwNumStatuses = 0;
    DWORD dwResumeHandle = 0;

    BSTR* pServiceNames = NULL;
    DWORD dwNumServiceNames = 0;

    BOOL bSuccess;
    DWORD dwError = 0;
    HRESULT hRes = S_OK;
    
    do
    {
        bSuccess = EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_STATE_ALL, lpStatuses, dwBytesAllocated, &dwBytesNeeded, &dwNumStatuses, &dwResumeHandle);
        if (!bSuccess)
        {   
            dwError = GetLastError();
            if ((dwError != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) &&
                (dwError != ERROR_MORE_DATA))
            {
                hRes = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
                goto Failed;
            }
        }

        if ((bSuccess || (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA)) &&
            (dwNumStatuses > 0))
        {
            BSTR *pTmpServiceNames = (BSTR*) CoTaskMemRealloc(pServiceNames, sizeof(BSTR) * (dwNumServiceNames + dwNumStatuses));
            if (!pTmpServiceNames)
            {
                hRes = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                goto Failed;
            }
            pServiceNames = pTmpServiceNames;

            for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwNumStatuses; ++i)
            {
                pServiceNames[dwNumServiceNames] = SysAllocString(lpStatuses[i].lpServiceName);
                if (!pServiceNames[dwNumServiceNames])
                {
                    hRes = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                    goto Failed;
                }
                ++dwNumServiceNames;
            }
        }

        if (!bSuccess)
        {
            LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS lpTmpStatuses = (LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS) realloc(lpStatuses, dwBytesNeeded);
            if (!lpTmpStatuses)
            {
                hRes = E_OUTOFMEMORY;
                goto Failed;
            }
            lpStatuses = lpTmpStatuses;
        }
    }
    while (!bSuccess);

    goto Finished;

Failed:
    if (pServiceNames)
    {
        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwNumServiceNames; ++i)
            SysFreeString(pServiceNames[i]);
        CoTaskMemFree(pServiceNames);
        pServiceNames = NULL;
    }
    dwNumServiceNames = 0;

Finished:
    free(lpStatuses);
    CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);

    *pServices = pServiceNames;
    *pdwServicesReturned = dwNumServiceNames;

    return hRes;
}
```

```
BSTR* pServiceNames = NULL;
DWORD dwServicesReturned = 0;
hr = pIService->GetServices(&pServiceNames, &dwServicesReturned);
if (hr == S_OK)
{
    ...
    for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwServicesReturned; ++i)
        SysFreeString(pServiceNames[i]);
    CoTaskMemFree(pServiceNames);
}
```

Alternatively, since you did tag the question as C++, you should use C++ idioms to help manage memory more effectively, eg:

```
struct SCHandle
{
    SC_HANDLE m_SC;

    SCHandle(SC_HANDLE hSC) : m_SC(hSC) {}
    ~SCHandle() { if (m_SC) CloseServiceHandle(m_SC); }

    bool operator !() const { return !m_SC; }
    operator SC_HANDLE() { return m_SC; }
};

STDMETHODIMP CServiceHandler::GetServices(BSTR** pServices, LPDWORD pdwServicesReturned)
{
    if (!(pServices && pdwServicesReturned))
        return E_POINTER;

    try
    {
        *pServices = NULL;
        *pdwServicesReturned = 0;

        SCHandle hSCManager(OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT | SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE));
        if (!hSCManager)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        std::vector<BYTE> statusBuffer;
        std::vector<std::wstring> serviceNames;

        LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS lpStatuses = NULL;
        DWORD dwBytesNeeded = 0;
        DWORD dwNumStatuses = 0;
        DWORD dwResumeHandle = 0;

        DWORD dwError = 0;
    
        do
        {
            BOOL bSuccess = EnumServicesStatus(hSCManager, SERVICE_WIN32, SERVICE_STATE_ALL, lpStatuses, statusBuffer.size(), &dwBytesNeeded, &dwNumStatuses, &dwResumeHandle);
            if (!bSuccess)
            {   
                dwError = GetLastError();
                if ((dwError != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) &&
                    (dwError != ERROR_MORE_DATA))
                    return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
            }

            if (bSuccess || (dwError == ERROR_MORE_DATA))
            {
                serviceNames.reserve(serviceNames.size() + dwNumStatuses);
                
                for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwNumStatuses; ++i)
                    serviceNames.push_back(lpStatuses[i].lpServiceName);
            }

            if (!bSuccess)
            {
                statusBuffer.resize(dwBytesNeeded);
                lpStatuses = reinterpret_cast<LPENUM_SERVICE_STATUS>(statusBuffer.data());
            }
        }
        while (!bSuccess);
        
        DWORD dwNumServiceNames = serviceNames.size();

        BSTR *pServiceNames = static_cast<BSTR*>(CoTaskMemAlloc(sizeof(BSTR) * dwNumServiceNames));
        if (!pServiceNames)
            return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

        for (DWORD i = 0; i < dwNumServiceNames; ++i)
        {
            pServiceNames[i] = SysAllocString(serviceNames[i].c_str());
            if (!pServiceNames[i])
            {
                for(DWORD j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                    SysFreeString(pServiceNames[j]);
                CoTaskMemFree(pServiceNames);
                return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
            }
        }

        *pServices = pServiceNames;
        *pdwServicesReturned = dwNumServiceNames;

        return S_OK;
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc &)
    {
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        return E_UNEXPECTED;
    }
}
```